# Linux x86: can't Open Blender

Tags: linux

my x is configured to execute blender (v.2.76b) but when I try to run the executable from terminal, It gives back this error:

```
$ ./blender
connect failed: No such file or directory
Read new prefs: /home/user/.config/blender/2.76/config/userpref.blend
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
intern/ghost/intern/GHOST_WindowX11.cpp:177: X11 glXQueryVersion() failed, verify working openGL system!
initial window could not find the GLX extension
Writing: /tmp/blender.crash.txt
Segmentation fault (core dump created)
```

what I don't read is why it prints:

> connect failed: no such file or directory

My O.S. is ubuntustudio 14.04 LTS, no blender pre-installation.

Blender downloaded from the official website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem of booting blender has been solved re-installing NVIDIA drivers.