# Is there anyway to install blender on ubuntu without root access?

Tags: installation, linux

I need to install blender on server which I don't have root access, is there any portable version of blender for ubuntu or any way to install it without root access? please help me if you know.

Answer (score 4):

Just download the latest Blender for Linux from [blender.org/download](https://www.blender.org/download/) (currently [2.78c for Linux 64bit](https://www.blender.org/download/Blender2.78/blender-2.78c-linux-glibc219-x86_64.tar.bz2/)), unpack the tar.bz2 file

```
tar xjf blender-2.78c-linux-glibc219-x86_64.tar.bz2
```

and run the "blender" executable from inside the unpacked folder

```
cd blender-2.78c-linux-glibc219-x86_64
./blender <options>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did that, but there is problem which says: Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":25.0".
/home/sources/blender-release/intern/ghost/intern/GHOST_WindowX11.cpp:299: X11 glXChooseVisual() failed, verify working openGL system!
initial window could not find the GLX extension

Comment: There must be some problem with the graphic card drivers installation: see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47836/linux-x86-cant-open-blender I'm not sure how you can fix this without root access.

Comment: I searched, but I don't have access to install card drivers :(

Comment: older cards are no more working with blender since 2.77 (and it will get worse soon), try to get 2.76b (zip or gzip) unpack and run blender as said above, to be sure...

Comment: @m.ardito Thanks, I did that but got the same problem: Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":25.0".
connect failed: No such file or directory
intern/ghost/intern/GHOST_WindowX11.cpp:216: X11 glXChooseVisual() failed, verify working openGL system!
initial window could not find the GLX extension

Comment: The answer to your question has been provided. You're now trying to get an answer to a different question, namely how to run Blender without proper OpenGL support. Please ask this in a different question, and accept this one as answered.